# React axios get method

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I am trying to read the value of `axios.get()` call in to the flag variable(the output is either true or false).

I am building a springboot+reactjs app.

Requirement of this code/Required flow of the code :

> Step 1 : enter username and password
>
> Step 2 : On click of button submit it should call handleChange()
>   method
>
> Step 3 : In the handle change method it should call the callFunction()
>   method.
>
> Step 4 : it should get the data from server and then move to the "THEN
>   BLOCK" where response is printed in console and an alert is given next
>   and then the value is returned to handle change method after which
>   another alert is given . But in step 4 the "THEN BLOCK" is not
>   executed and it just jumps so value in handleChange() method is
>   undefined . But after whole process is done at last the THEN block is
>   executed.

Can you tell what is the issue and what am i missing I require output as :

> 1.response.Data( which is either true or false which i recieve from get http call) in console
>
> 2.alert box showing the response.data
>
> 3. Return value
> 4. In console -> response.data(true or false) is the response
>
>    5.alert ( you have entered username: shaik and password : ****)

Current output i receive is :

> 1.In console -> "undefined" is the response
>
> 2.alert ( you have entered username: shaik and password : ****)
>
> 3.response.Data( which is either true or false which i recieve from get http call) in console
>
> 4.alert box showing the response.data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            password: ''
        };
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.callFuction = this.callFuction.bind(this);
    }

    updateState(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handleChange = (event) => {
        debugger;
        var flag = this.callFuction();

        console.log(flag +"is the response")
        alert("You have entered : \n User Name :" + this.state.userName + " \n Password :" + this.state.password);

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    callFuction(){
        debugger;   
          axios.get('http://localhost:8086/login/check?userName='+this.state.userName+'&password='+this.state.password ).then(response => {
            debugger;
            console.log(response.data);    
            alert(response.data);
            return response.data;
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <form >
                <label>User Name:
                <input type="text" name ="userName"  onChange={this.updateState} />
                </label>
                <label>Password:
                <input type="password" name = "password" onChange={this.updateState} />
                </label>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleChange} />
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `undefined` because you return nothing from your `callFunction`, you should return result of `axios` get, but it will returning promise, so you should set flag after `promise` resolving.

Here is short example:

```
 handleChange = (event) => {
    this.callFunction()
      .then(flag => {
         console.log(flag +" is the response")
    alert("You have entered : \n User Name :" + this.state.userName + " \n Password :" + this.state.password);
      });


    event.preventDefault();
}

callFuction(){  
      return axios.get('http://localhost:8086/login/check?userName='+this.state.userName+'&password='+this.state.password ).then(response => {
        return response.data;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work but not in the way i expected . Can you tell me as to why we need to add return statement twice in callFunction() method and also as to when i call the handlechange() the flow is different, the "return response.data " is reiterated later again

Comment: In short the flow is as follows :  1. click button ->this.callFunction()-> it iterates the http request but next doesnt move into the method where return response.data is present -> it breaks out of the function and goes back to this.callFunction()  -> here it again doesn't enter the then() loop . The response.data and then () loop are iterated again later . How does this occur...... I am a backend developer so i am going with step by step flow so i am bit confused here

Comment: Because if you not returning `axios.get` . promise, you will got undefined, because you returning nothing in this function.

Comment: If  i add the alert box outside callFunction() block then it gets executed first and then the console value with in the callFunction() block is then executed. Isn't this a wrong flow